# Create a facebook notification with Django package facepy : [15] (#15) This method must be called with an app access_token

Tags: python, django, notifications, fandjango

I'm trying to create a facebook notifications with facepy & fandjango but I'm constantly get the same Error,

```
@facebook_authorization_required
@csrf_exempt     
def notify_self(request):

     token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token #user token
     token_app=facepy.utils.get_application_access_token('APP_ID','APP_SECRET_ID') 
     graph = GraphAPI(token)
     graph.post(
        path = 'me/notifications',
        template = '#Text of the notification',
        href = 'URL',
        access_token= token_app
     )

     return HttpResponse('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>top.location.href = \'URL\';</script>')<code>
```

When I Check the app access_token on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ it said that it's a valid token (I get back my APP's ID)

I also try with

> graph = GraphAPI(token_app)

but it send me:

> [2500] An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

my app have all the permission that I need, I search for a while but didn't find any help so I'm asking here.

Edit: The correct Code is

```
@facebook_authorization_required
@csrf_exempt     
def notify_self(request):
   token_app=facepy.utils.get_application_access_token('APP_ID','APP_SECRET_ID') 
   graph = GraphAPI(token_app)
   graph.post(
      path = 'me/notifications',
      template = '#Text of the notification',
      href = 'URL'
   ) 

   return HttpResponse('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>top.location.href = \'URL\'</script>')
```

thanks to [joaopsf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334446/joaopsf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found where was the issues.
when I was trying with

> graph = GraphAPI(token_app)

I was on the good way, the only things to do was to delete

> access_token= token_app

the token is saved when at the instruction GraphAPI(token_app) so there is no need to give it again.

The correct code is :

```
@facebook_authorization_required
@csrf_exempt     
def notify_self(request):

   token = request.facebook.user.oauth_token.token #user token
   token_app=facepy.utils.get_application_access_token('APP_ID','APP_SECRET_ID') 
   graph = GraphAPI(token)
   graph.post(
      path = 'me/notifications',
      template = '#Text of the notification',
      href = 'URL',
      access_token= token_app
   ) 

   return HttpResponse('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>top.location.href = \'URL\'</script>')
```

Hope that will help someone

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I found a different solution that did work; I'll post it as an answer below.

Also, the code you posted in your answer is identical to the code you posted in the question -- you might want to check that out and fix the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When creating notifications, you should use the **app token**, not the user token. So, the *token = ...* line is not necessary.

In addition, since you are using an app token rather than an user token, you cannot use "*me/...*" in the path; you must specify the user ID.

This is what worked for me:

```
@facebook_authorization_required
@csrf_exempt
def notify_self(request):
    token_app = facepy.utils.get_application_access_token(
        settings.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_ID,
        settings.FACEBOOK_APPLICATION_SECRET_KEY
    )
    graph = GraphAPI(token_app)
    graph.post(
        path='%s/notifications' % request.facebook.user.facebook_id,
        template='#Text of the notification',
        href='my targe URL',
    )
    return 'etc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Jiloko Has forgotten to update the code, I tried the code and the correct code is here:

```
@facebook_authorization_required
@csrf_exempt     
def notify_self(request):
   token_app=facepy.utils.get_application_access_token('APP_ID','APP_SECRET_ID') 
   graph = GraphAPI(token_app)
   graph.post(
      path = 'me/notifications',
      template = '#Text of the notification',
      href = 'URL'
   ) 

   return HttpResponse('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>top.location.href = \'URL\'</script>')
```

you can change 'me/notifications' for 'USER_ID/notifications'