# Django facebook library

Tags: php, python, django, facebook

I have a question in regard to Facebook notifications implemented in Django

For a project I have used FBIgnite, it's a php framework based on Codeigniter. It has some functions for Facebook, like "send a notification" on Facebook. I want to know if there's something like that for Django.

I did some research and found only something for auth, like django-facebook-connect, djanfo-socialauth, django-socialall etc.

I'm interested in using:

1. Facebook authentication (only login & getting some data)
2. Sending from my framework Facebook notifications. ex: `myfunc(fbid='', msg='');`

Does anybody know something like this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

The combination of [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for authentication/registration and [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) is a winning team.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll give it a try. It is better django-socialauth ? And another question: With facepy, can I send facebook notifications ? THe php sdk, let's you send facebook notifications. I want to know if I can do the same stuff with a 3rd party lib in django. Thank you !

Comment: Yeah, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309523/create-a-facebook-notification-with-django-package-facepy-15-15-this-meth